# How can I write some formulas on visual std c++ (in "class" types)

Tags: visual-c++

I should make a menu driver program on visual studio c++ , but there are some conditions , main cpp files should have include #eee.h and   eee.h header file should have 9 class for each of 9 formula (some electric formulas) groups and their member functions for computations. I understand algorithm but (((((I can't write formulas on class))))      edit:I have some codes about how to solve that formula.These are simple easy codes.     I'm new on programming :(

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUrN1.jpg   others are more easier formulas ı dont know how can ı entegreted class type and menu driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better understand algorithms and such, here's a helpful [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/)

Best of luck,

Fox~